# pycharm on windows and docker in linux vm

Tags: docker, pycharm

By any chance can Pycharm on Windows be configured to run docker inside a linux VM (VirtualBox) ?

Meaning that i would like to take advantage of the Pycharm Docker tools of professional version but avoid installing docker for windows, since im using Linux VMs that have Docker installed.

Tried to set the tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:2375 of the guest host vm but failing. Not sure if this can be done at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no native support, but you can configure PyCharm to work with remote Docker daemon. Basically you need a deployment configuration alongside the Docker-based remote interpreter to transfer the project files to remote machine where they can be mounted inside a container.

See the detailed instruction in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33489 and please vote for the ticket if you want this support to be a first-class citizen in PyCharm.

Comment: thanks , ok i upvoted on the ticket . meanwile will test the workaround.